# Correct voting results count are visible only after clearing cache manually in drupal 7

Tags: api, drupal-7, anonymous, voting, drupal-fivestar

In one of my site I am using voting api and five star module.

When anonymous user rate the product then vote is increased by one and
then if we refresh the page old vote count is displayed
if we refresh the page by putting ?fsdfsd after the url then correct vote count will display.

I added

```
hook_votingapi_results($cached, $entity_type, $entity_id) {
    $uri = entity_uri($entity_type, node_load($entity_id));
    $path = url($uri['path'], array('absolute' => TRUE));
    cache_clear_all($path, 'cache_page', TRUE);
    cache_clear_all("field:$entitytype:$entityid", 'cache_field');
    cache_clear_all("field:node:$nid", 'cache_field');
}
```

and it is page caching issue for anonymous users only. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Configuration>Performance is the option to disable "Cache pages for anonymous users"

Comment: No, its not preferable.